# napi used for receiving

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel

I am trying to write a module which is similar to ping. The problem is coming in receiving the packet. The code is shown below:

```
#include<asm/uaccess.h>
#include<linux/sched.h>
#include<linux/wait.h>
#include<linux/netfilter.h>
#include<linux/netfilter_ipv4.h>

struct net_device *dev;
struct sk_buff *skb;
struct napi_struct *rnapi;

int rrpoll(struct napi_struct *napi,int budget)
{
   printk(KERN_ALERT"we are HEARRR%s,%d\n",__func__,__LINE__);
   skb = (struct sk_buff *)kmalloc(sizeof(struct sk_buff *),GFP_KERNEL);
   netif_receive_skb(skb);
   kfree(skb);
   return 0;
  }

static int rec_init(void)
{
  dev =  __dev_get_by_name(&init_net,"wlan0");
  rnapi = (struct napi_struct *)kmalloc(sizeof(struct napi_struct *),GFP_KERNEL);
  netif_napi_add(dev,rnapi,&rrpoll,100);
  napi_schedule(rnapi);
  return 0;
  }

static void rec_exit(void)
{
  //napi_complete(rnapi);
    netif_napi_del(rnapi);
}
```

The modules compiles and runs without any error, but the whole system hangs after some time.

Comment: "the whole system hangs after some time" is insufficient for anybody to tell you what's wrong, or even if your code is responsible for the hang, or if it is, whether or not the problem is in the code you posted or elsewhere.

Comment: @JimGarrison   i have made a new module just for recieving any packet(just for checking) and its the above code.......

Comment: @JimGarrison "after some time" means whenever i install my module then it hangs and the system doen't hang when the module is not installed.....

Comment: A lot of C code compiles without error, but that doesn't mean it's correct.  In this case I don't think NAPI is what you want to use.  NAPI is designed for acting between the kernel and device driver.  It looks like you're trying to add a hook for acting on packets.  I'd suggest looking into netfilter instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see a couple of problems with your sample code:

1. the skb should be allocated by alloc_skb() not kmalloc
2. after you call netif_receive_skb, you should not free the skb.  Your code is no longer the owner of that skb since you've given it to the network stack.
3. I don't see you filling in the skb in any way.  Maybe you are just simplifying the code.  But as it is now, you are sending up an uninitialized (or if you use alloc_skb, initialized but empty) skb to the networking stack.

Michael